# Count number of nonlinear iterations in FMU

Tags: simulation, dymola, fmi

---

Hello

I'm running an FMU model using FMILibrary directly. 
The model has a certain size of non-linear system.
I would like to get the information of how many non-linear iteration were needed at every time step. Something similar what Dymola returns when selecting SimulationSetup-->Debug-->Nonlinear Iterations would be nice.

Any idea how to get to that information?

Thanks

Comment: Could you please provide more information on the FMU? From which tool is it exported? FMI 1.0, 2.0? ME or CS type?

Comment: Hello Christian. So the exporting tool is Dymola 2017 FD01. It's for both, FMI 1.0 and FMI 2.0. I'm interested in ME models. The reason for this is that I noticed some performance differences between the models, exported with different fmi versions. I tried to avoid as many dependencies as possible with running it directly with FMI Library. As the models contain non-lin systems, I would like to check if their solving is different between the two FMI versions.

Comment: I would think that solving nonlinear systems is not exposed to the importing tool in FMI 2.0.  However, it could be present in the logging information. The FMI Standard 2.0 section 2.2.4 suggests a category "logNonlinearSystems: Log the solution of nonlinear systems of equations."

Comment: I think this might work. Thanks!